# Android bluetooth gets paired, connected but never receives data to a TextView

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino

I am trying to receive data (string) from an non android bluetooth device (arduino with HC-06). Code inside arduino looks pretty fine it sends a string in a continuous loop and i was able to see it using a serial monitor. 
But when i try to use it with my android phone, it gets paired, connected and shows "Connect" in a toast but i was never able to receive its string and display it on the text view. Please tell me if i have done anything wrong.

Code inside my activity class, inside onCreate method:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what)
            {
            case SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect", 0).show()

                break;

            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[])msg.obj;
                String string = new String(readBuf);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();              
                tvTest.setText(string);
```

Inside ConnectedThread class:

```
public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                buffer = new byte[1024];
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, 0).show();` where you've a `0` put `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`

Comment: i guess its just a matter of showing the duration of the toast?
plus Toast works fine for "SUCCESS_CONNECT" 
maybe it never comes to the "case MESSAGE_READ" to execute its operations

Comment: Try it. As you are not defining time for your toast maybe it isn't getting showed. If this doesnt't work, we should watch deeper.

Comment: tried it, it does not work. i dont think its the case btw, 
i tried removing all the code in "case MESSAGE_READ" and kept only 
tvTest.setText("Message read"); but my Text View doesn't change. I assume "case MESSAGE_READ" never gets called.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the run() method of your connectedThread class, another inside your activity's handleMessage() method and debug it. See if the code goes through it until the MESSAGE_READ case. We will try to localize the problem step by step but try doing this first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by calling

```
connectedThread.start();
```

after,

```
ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
```

line in SUCCESS_CONNECT case.